# Where to find compiz profiles online to load into my ubuntu?

Tags: ccsm

I am a very newbie using `CompizConfig Setting Manager` and usually any edit I make with it doesn't bring good effects.

So I wonder, Is there a *repository* so I can find `CCSM` config files so I can import on my Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Things to consider before continuing running CCSM are:

Ubuntu runs very smooth with all Intel chipsets, processors and graphics cards.
Is your processor fairly new like a minimum i3? CCSM requires quite a few resources, does your system has the sufficient resources to support all the eyecandy? Make sure you have plenty of ram at least 3GB or higher?
From Software and Updates, have your ran the additional drivers feature for drivers updates and detection of third party drivers that might not be well supported for the Ubuntu version that you are running.

cheers